# What's the reason behind SpaceX's timing of launching Starlink satellites?

Tags: spacex, starlink, launch-window

I noticed a pattern in the timing of Starlink launches: In the first half of each year, Starlink launches occur rather during the day, and in the second half, they occur rather during the night (regardless of launch site, whether it's Florida or Vandenberg). Of course, this doesn't change abruptly, but fluid. The pattern changes slowly toward daytime launches during the first half of the year and in the 2nd half towards nighttime launches. What exactly is the reason why Starlink sats are rather launched during the day in the first half and rather at night during the 2nd half of the year?

Comment: A quick check back shows that this is not always true. A few in the 2nd half of the year during daytime, and loads in the 1st half launching during darkness.

Comment: @RoryAlsop That's why I wrote "rather". And some also launch at twilight.

Comment: Checking the first few launches in 2023 seems to contradict your pattern. It would help if you could compile a table to prove your point.

Comment: @asdfex The transience is fluid. You must not expect that on 31 Dec launches occur during midnight and on 1 Jan they'd occur during midday.